# unzip downloaded file through asihttprequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, asihttprequest, unzip

I want to know whether using ASIHTTPRequest we can unzip a .zip downloaded file or it can only
unzip .gzip compressed file.

Please let me know because if ASIHTTPRequest cannot unzip .zip compressed file then I will have to use third party api like ZipArchive to unzip the downloaded file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not using gzip compressed HTTP communication which would be transparently decoded for you by ASI (and virtually all other HTTP access frameworks).

ASIHTTP supports decompression, for example -

```
- (IBAction)grabURL:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *url              = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // YES is the default, you can turn off gzip compression by setting this to NO
    [request setAllowCompressedResponse:YES];

    [request startSynchronous];
    BOOL *dataWasCompressed    = [request isResponseCompressed]; // Was the response gzip compressed?
    NSData *compressedResponse = [request rawResponseData]; // Compressed data
    NSData *uncompressedData   = [request responseData]; // Uncompressed data
    NSString *response         = [request responseString]; // Uncompressed data as a string
}
```

**UPDATE:** incase asi does not support zip file decompression then I've used [ZipArchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/) with success in the past.

It's pretty ligthweight and simple to use, supports password protection, multiple files inside a ZIP, as well as compress & decompress. so you need to first fetch the zip file through asi and then unzip is using ziparchive.

The basic usage is:

```
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ZipFileName" ofType:@"zip"];
ZipArchive *zipArchive = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
[zipArchive UnzipOpenFile:filepath Password:@"xxxxxx"];
[zipArchive UnzipFileTo:{pathToDirectory} overWrite:YES];
[zipArchive UnzipCloseFile];
[zipArchive release];
```

Comment: so u mean to say we can only unzip gzip compressed data not zip compressed data through asi.

Comment: try it out. see if it works. if zip is not working in asi. then see my update above.